# How many solutions does $2 (\sin^{-1}x)^2 -5\sin^{-1}x+2=0$ have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, quadratics

> Number of solutions of the equation
> $2 (\sin^{-1}x)^2 -5\sin^{-1}x+2=0 $

Let
$t=\sin^{-1}x $

$2 t^2 -5t+2=0$

$(t-2)(2t-1)=0 $

$t=2$    or $t=1/2$

Then

$\sin^{-1}x=2\quad$  or$\quad   \sin^{-1}x=1/2$

$x=\sin 2\quad$  or$\quad  x=\sin(1/2)$

Did I do something wrong here? I found a solution here =>  https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/number-of-solutions-of-the-equation-2sin1x25sin1x20/

The solution given on this site says only one solution exists. But I can't understand why $x=\sin 2$   is rejecting. isn't $t$ is an angle and $x$ is a value? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reject $x=\sin 2$ as $\arcsin x$ is defined on $[-1,1]$ **and takes values in $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ by definition**. As $2$ doesn’t belong to the last interval, this solution has to be rejected.

See [inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: isn't t is an angle and x is a value?

Comment: $\sin^{-1} x = \arcsin x$ is indeed an angle. Which belongs to $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ by definition of $\arcsin$.

Answer (score 2):

The (real-valued) arcsine returns a number in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. In particular $\arcsin\sin2$ is not $2$, but $\pi-2$, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the other responses as well as the *official* answer, because I consider the normal range of the ArcSin function as irrelevant.

Consider the equation $t^2 = 2.$  The fact that the square root function has a normal range of non-negative values only is irrelevant.  The equation $t^2 = 2$ still has two solutions, not one.

Just because the ArcSin function normally has a restricted range does not render the equation ArcSin$(x) = 2$ as gibberish.  Here, $x$ can be reasonably interpreted as *representing* the $\sin(2)$.

Ultimately, it comes down to interpretation.  Do you interpret the equation ArcSin$(x) = 2$ to mean that $2$ is the result of the ArcSin function at some value $x$ (which would imply that this equation has no solution), or do you interpret the equation as *find* $x$ such that $\sin(2) = x.$

Note that the $\sin^{(-1)}$ syntax is being used instead of ArcSin.  It is not that unusual, when faced with a **non-injective** function $f(x)=y$ to interpret $f^{(-1)}(y)$ to represent all of the values of $x$ such that $f(x) = y.$

Very similarly, do you interpret the equation $t^2 = 2$ as find $t$ such that $t^2 = 2$, or do you interpret it as find $t$ such that $t = \sqrt{2}.$